# What is the difference between the following constructors of the java.lang.Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

> 1.new Thread(Runnable target);
>
> 2.new Thread();

I get the first one, but what is the point of the second one, which class does it start the thread on?

Comment: Have a look at the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: If you choose to extend Thread, you can override the Thread's run method directly, and you don't need to pass it a Runnable.

Comment: @immibis: Of course. You nailed it buddy. Thanks.

Comment: Is it also true that we must always look to implement the Runnable interface as opposed to extending the Thread class because if we use the extends, the class can no longer extend any more classes?

Comment: @Pretorious Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first constructor allow you to pass any class that implements `Runnable` which allow you to override the `run` method in that class.

If you create a thread with the second constructor, you can directly override the run method that way :

```
new Thread(){
   @Override
   public void run()
   {

   }
};
```

Comment: @Pretorious To resume, if you only need to create a Thread on the fly where you know the run method's behaviour won't be re-used, simply use the second constructor. If you want to re-define your own implementation  of Runnable then you will need to create a class that implement `Runnable` hence create thread using this class and the first constructor.

Comment: @Pretorious it's an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Thanks man. You always provide very good answers. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Pretorious You're welcome. Thanks for your politeness.

Answer (score 0):

The second constructor is for subclassing `Thread`, either anonymous (see answer by @Jean-François Savard) or as usual:

```
class YourThread extends Thread {
    YourThread() {
        // implicit super()
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your thread code
    }
}
```